# Finding critical value using t-distribution in Excel

Tags: statistics, math-software

Alright, I'm trying to figure out how to calculate a  critical value using t-distribution in Microsoft Excel... ex. a one-tailed area of 0.05 with 39 degrees of freedom: t=1.685

I know the answer, but how do I get this? I've tried TDIST() TINV() and TTEST() but they all give me different answers. This web calculator: http://www.danielsoper.com/statcalc/calc10.aspx always gives me what I'm looking for but I cannot manage to get Excel to do the same.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hi Tim. SE has a site dedicated to statistics questions at stats.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 4):

The right function is `TINV()`, but the problem is that `TINV()` assumes that you're inputting the two-tailed probability, not the one-tailed probability.  In other words, `TINV(p,d)` outputs the value of $x$ such that $P(|X| \geq x) = p$, where $X$ has a $t$ distribution with $d$ degrees of freedom.

Thus if you want  `TINV()` to give you the critical value associated with a one-tailed probability, you have to double the probability first to account for the other tail.  Thus, for example, `TINV(0.1,39)` yields an output of `1.684875122`, which is the critical value you want.

Answer (score 2):

Non-answer: Export the data to CSV and use software that is suited for statistical work, e.g. R.

Answer (score 2):

For reference, in EXCEL 2010 there are now two functions: `T.INV()`, which gives the "left-tailed inverse" (i.e. the inverse of the cumulative distribution function), and there is `T.INV.2T()`, which assumes as an argument the probability of both tails.

Answer (score 1):

As Mike suggested either you can input your alpha level (nominal alpha) as .10 (2*.05) to get the one tailed p value or you can divide the given probability (actual alpha) by two. Both approaches do the same thing. Remember that taking all other things constant, the probability of recting a true null is easier for a one tailed test compared to the two tailed test. One tailed test yields a smaller p value compared to the two tailed test. That is why you should dived the calculated p (actual alpha) by 2. Same goes for SPSS. Hope it helps :)  Gulshah